# I want to change the direction of the ScrollView, but it reverses everything

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to get the ScrollView to start the show from right to left

I found this solution, but it reversed everything the wrong way

```
.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
```

Adding this to ScrollView

I just want to reverse the start of ScrollView, not everything

```
struct AdsView: View {

var body: some View {
    
    VStack(spacing: 1){
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(0..<5) { item in
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Image("test")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .cornerRadius(20)
                            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 20, x: 20, y: 20)
                        .frame(maxWidth: 150, maxHeight: 200)
                        
                        Text("start here")
                        Text("new").foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    }
                }
            }.padding()
        }
        .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to use opposite scales for a `ScrollView` and content.

Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

[image: demo]

Here is main part:

```
        .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: -1, height: 1))
    }
    .scaleEffect(CGSize(width: -1, height: 1))
```

[Test module in project is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestRightToLeftScrollView.swift)

Comment: give me error [Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16cec7f80)]